# Detect MouseDown with KeyPressed

Tags: xamarin, custom-view, xamarin.mac

Is there a way to detect if a key like **Shift** on any mouse event like **MouseDown** in a Xamarin.mac Application? I've got some custom views loaded into a StackView which should all be selectable. Selecting a single view is no problem, but I want to select multiple views like the standard selection pattern with Shift, Command, etc.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `NSEvent` of your `MouseDown` event you can check the `ModifierFlags` property for any *modifier* keys being pressed by the user.

```
    public override void MouseDown(NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        base.MouseDown(theEvent);
        // Report true if the user is holding the CMD down while performing a mouse down
        Console.WriteLine(theEvent.ModifierFlags.HasFlag(NSEventModifierMask.CommandKeyMask));
    }
```

The modifier keys that you can check for:

```
public enum NSEventModifierMask : ulong
{
    AlphaShiftKeyMask = 65536uL,
    ShiftKeyMask = 131072uL,
    ControlKeyMask = 262144uL,
    AlternateKeyMask = 524288uL,
    CommandKeyMask = 1048576uL,
    NumericPadKeyMask = 2097152uL,
    HelpKeyMask = 4194304uL,
    FunctionKeyMask = 8388608uL,
    DeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask = 4294901760uL
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you a lot!!